# Custom Google Sheets function to add an item to a comma delimited list

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have comma separated lists in a Google Sheet, like "apple,banana". I need a function to add elements to this list, like so `=SETADD("apple,banana","carrot")`, which should return the value "apple,banana,carrot".

```js
function SETADD(list, item) {
  var array = list.split(',');
  if (!array.includes(item)) {
    return list + ',' + item;
  }
  else {
    return list;
  }
}
```

This function returns with an error `TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object apple,banana. (line 3).` It looks like the first argument to the function is not a string? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, in the current stage, `Array.includes()` cannot be used at Google Apps Script, yet. So as a workaround, how about this modification?

#### From:

```
if (!array.includes(item)) {
```

#### To:

```
if (array.indexOf(item) === -1) {
```

#### References:

- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that you are running your code in an interpreter which doesn't support include. Try to use es5 code or switch to a node version which supports include (according to [node.green](https://node.green/) its v6.4+).

I would suggest to change your code:

```
function SETADD(list, item) {
  var array = list.split(',');
  if (list.indexOf(','+item+',') > -1 || list.startsWith(item+',') || list.endsWith(','+item)) {
    return list;
  }
  else {
    return list + ',' + item;
  }
}
```