# Sorting raw data from one sheet into separate tabs on a new sheet in Google App Script

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, google-apps-script, filter

I have a large data file that I want to be separated/filtered out into separate tabs on a new sheet. They need to be filtered by a certain column containing "BGT" within the string.

I am very new to using Google Apps Script so this is a work in progress. I am able to pull the data from one sheet into another, convert it to an array and assign the column I want to sort by. I just can't properly set up the filter.

```
function CreativeReport() {

  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.openByUrl(SPREADSHEET_URL);
  var sheet = ss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

  var folder = getDriveFolderFromPath("Daily Creative Audit");

  var fileId = folder.getFiles().next().getId();

  var RawMM = SpreadsheetApp.openById(fileId);
  var ArrayRawData = RawMM.getRange(2,1,RawMM.getLastRow()-1,5).getValues();

  var ConceptName = RawMM.getRange('A:A').getValues();
  var BGTFilter = ConceptName.includes("BGT");
  var BGTFilteredData = ArrayRawData.filter(function(item){ return item [6] === BGTFilter;}); 

  Logger.log(BGTFilteredData);
```

The column I want to sort buy contains cells formatted like this

```
2019_BGT_Bigsale_300x50  
2019_SWT_Bigsale_300x50  
2019_AI_Bigsale_300x50  
2019_SWO_Bigsale_300x50  
2019_DCO_Bigsale_300x50.
```

The goal is to have the script filter this raw data, and sort it into separate sheets depending on the cells containing:

```
BGT  
SWO  
SWT  
AI  
DCO
```

The code I how SHOULD log out just the concepts containing "BGT" in the string but I get

```
TypeError: Cannot find function includes in object ,concept_name,
```

Comment: Values retrieved by ``getValues()`` is 2 dimensional array. So if ``Array.includes()`` can be used at Google Apps Script, in your script, ``ConceptName.includes("BGT")`` is always ``false``. And, unfortunately, ``Array.includes()`` cannot be used at Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55966256/7108653) By the way, can I ask you about ``sort it into separate sheets depending on the cells containing:``? There are 5 sheets for ``BGT, SWO, SWT, AI, DCO``. For example, you want to put ``2019_BGT_Bigsale_300x50 `` to the sheet name of ``BGT``. Is my understanding correct?

Comment: Exactly. It should take all info that is in the same row as well

Comment: Thank you for replying. I think that in your script, an error occurs at ``var ArrayRawData = RawMM.getRange(2,1,RawMM.getLastRow()-1,20).getValues();``, because ``getRange(row, column, numRows, numColumns)`` is the method of Class Sheet. So in order to correctly understand your situation, can you provide a sample Spreadsheet? Of course, please remove your personal information.

Comment: Here is a small sample list. There would normally be more columns with other metrics but this is simpler for now. [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DEyJfTLb6g-OST-9m-7a5fxLaBOzjeFqhW-KOk20lPc/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying and sharing the sample. In your script, it seems that the column "G" has ``ConceptName``. But your shared sample Spreadsheet has no column "G". And the sheet is only one in the Spreadsheet. So I couldn't understand about what you want to do. Can you explain about your goal? In this case, can you update your question for the sample Spreadsheet? By the way, when your script was modified using the shared Spreadsheet, can the script be used for your actual Spreadsheet? I'm worry about this.

Comment: Hi, I went and updated the code in the question to reflect the sample data I provided. The goal is to have one sheet with all of the raw data [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1DEyJfTLb6g-OST-9m-7a5fxLaBOzjeFqhW-KOk20lPc/edit#gid=0) and for the script to create a new sheet, and sort the data into separate tabs as shown here: [link] (https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1KFQvFTOCIzi4iEQK8pWIPH2uaFH64vBvDbxWok50ARk/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: Thank you for replying and adding the information. I thought that I could understand about your goal. I proposed a modified script as an answer. Could you please confirm it? If I misunderstood your question and that was not the result you want, I apologize.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You have values at "Sheet1" in the source Spreadsheet.
- You want to separate the values by checking whether the column "A" has the values of `BGT, SWO, SWT, AI, DCO`.
- You want to put the separated values to the sheet names of `BGT, SWO, SWT, AI, DCO` in the destination Spreadsheet.

I could understand like above. If my understanding is correct, how about this modification? Unfortunately, the modified script was largely changed from your original script. I apologize for this. I think that there are several answers for your situation. So please think of this as just one of them.

The flow of the modified script is as follows.

1. Retrieve values from the source sheet.
2. Create an object for retrieving values for each destination sheet.

   - The object is like  `{"BGT": [values], "SWO": [values],,,}`.
3. Put values for the destination sheets.

#### Modified script:

Before you run the script, please set `srcSpreadsheetId`, `dstSpreadsheetId` and `srcSheetName`.

```
function CreativeReport() {
  // Variables: Please set them for your situation.
  var srcSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the source Spreadsheet ID. In your sample, the Spreadsheet name is "Sample Raw Data".
  var dstSpreadsheetId = "###"; // Please set the destination Spreadsheet ID. In your sample, the Spreadsheet name is "Sorted Data".
  var srcSheetName = "Sheet1"; // Please modify this. In this sample, it's the same with your sample Spreadsheet.
  var dstSheetNames = ["BGT", "SWO", "DCO", "AI", "SWT"];

  // Open Spreadsheets
  var srcSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(srcSpreadsheetId);
  var dstSS = SpreadsheetApp.openById(dstSpreadsheetId);

  // Retrieve values from the source sheet.
  var srcSheet = srcSS.getSheetByName(srcSheetName);
  var srcValues = srcSheet.getRange(2, 1, srcSheet.getLastRow() - 1, 5).getValues();

  // Create an object for retrieving values for each destination sheet.
  var object = srcValues.reduce(function(obj, e) {
    dstSheetNames.forEach(function(f) {
      if (e[0].indexOf(f) > -1) obj[f] = obj[f] ? obj[f].concat([e]) : [e];
    });
    return obj;
  }, {});

  // Put values for the destination sheets.
  dstSheetNames.forEach(function(e) {
    var sheet = dstSS.getSheetByName(e);
    sheet.getRange(sheet.getLastRow() + 1, 1, object[e].length, object[e][0].length).setValues(object[e]);
  });
}
```

#### Note:

- As mentioned at my comment, the values retrieved by `getValues()` is 2 dimensional array. So if `Array.includes()` can be used at Google Apps Script, in your script, `ConceptName.includes("BGT")` is always `false`. And, unfortunately, `Array.includes()` cannot be used at Google Apps Script. [Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55966256/7108653)
- This modified script was prepared using the sample Spreadsheets of "Sample Raw Data" and "Sorted Data" you shared. So if your actual Spreadsheet is different from these samples, please modify above script.
- When the values of source Spreadsheet and the number of destination sheets are much increased, I recommend to use Sheets API for putting the values for each destination sheet.

#### References:

- [getValues()](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getvalues)
- [Basic JavaScript features](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/services/#basic_javascript_features)
- [includes()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/includes)
- [indexOf()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)
- [reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
- [for​Each()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach)

Comment: Thank you so much! This is just what I needed.

Comment: @Cameron Potter Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved.